# time difference is zero sec

Tags: c, time

Here i am trying to count to calculate time required to complete merge sort.But the difference between start and end is showing zero secend.I don't know what is the problem.For convenience i am posting only the main function where time is calculated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
    clock_t start,end,diff;
    start=clock();
    int arr[4]={12,2,56,1};
    int i;
    printf("beforn sort\n");
    printf("\n-------------\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n \n");
    Merge_sort(arr,0,3);
    printf("after merge sort\n");
    printf("\n-------------\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    end=clock();
    diff=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("total time is %f sec ",diff);
}
```

Comment: perhaps it took less than a second

Comment: More to the point, perhaps it took less than the resolution of the clock. Merge-sorting a 4-element array will be *very quick*.

Comment: That is unless the processor is *very slow*...

Comment: More to the point, if `clock_t` is an integer type, `printf("total time is %f sec ",diff);` is undefined behavior for passing the wrong type to `printf("%f")`.

Comment: How about changing the type of `diff` to `double`?

Comment: Rewrite it in Ruby.  Buy a calendar.

Comment: The issue appears you have too few elements in your sort to give anything other than the trivial answer of "it's in the noise". Generally for a good valid sort comparison, you are going to need million or ten-million data set to sort. Even 1- 5 million sort iterations can be in the millisecond noise not discernible from other normal computing operations. If you have a a small set, either duplicate it to make it larger, or run the sort a million times and you will get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clock()` returns the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program was launched. So that

```
start=clock();
```

gives number of clock ticks from program launched till `clock()` is called.
Which gives you clock ticks before sorting.This is number of clock ticks, not seconds.

After sort

```
end=clock()
```

gives number of clock ticks from program launched till `clock()` is called.
Which gives you clock ticks after sorting.This is number of clock ticks, not seconds.

Now `end-start` gives number of clock ticks during sorting process.(This also is not in seconds)

> (Number of clock ticks)/(Number of clock ticks in one second)= time in seconds

`(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` gives time required for the sorting process in seconds. But in C this gives an integer. So it has to typecasted to double for precision. That gives.

```
double diff;
diff=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is defined to be type `clock_t`, which is defined to be an arithmetic type, in N1256 7.23.1. It suggests that `clock_t` may be an integer type.

I suppose you should change the type of `diff` to `double`. Doing so will also make the last usage of `printf()` correct.

Comment: thanks, it works !! why dividing by CLOCK_Per_SECOND giving me time in sec...this is confusing.I know this is another question,but can u answer please?

Comment: Dimensional Analysis will reveal the answer to your new question.